# How to check actual list of arguments being passed to subprocess.Popen process handler?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, popen

I am using Python and using `subprocess.Popen` to invoke a system call. I am passing pretty long string i.e. `self.description` value under the `subprocess.Popen` argument as shown below.

```
firstProcess = subprocess.Popen(["echo",self.description], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

However, i am getting this error that says: `Argument list too long`

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
OSError: [Errno 7] Argument list too long
```

Some time above code works and some times it won't work depending on the contents of the `'self.description'` string.

How can i make the above code work by forcing `subprocess.Popen` to consider `self.description` as one single string OR how can i print the list of param values that are actually being passed to `subprocess.Popen(["echo",self.description]` method as it seems like `self.description` is splitted into multiple parameters and passed to the `subprocess.Popen` method?

Comment: If `self.description` contains space characters, you should enclose the string in double quote (`"`) characters.

Comment: can you print (for us) the contents of self.description?  It's likely that this is formatted incorrectly fro popen

Comment: It is about 200 Kb data in size. Some sample data: F  24 U:  0 Pi: 1 G:22 E:    462 H:0 A:  A stat (id  384 val 0x0000000002CC908F) P:00000004 I2: -ba-classification
F  24 U:  0 Pi: 1 G:22 E:    464 H:0 A:  A stat (id  386 val 0x0000000000001224) P:00000004 I2: -ba-classification
F  24 U:  0 Pi: 1 G:22 E:    494 H:0 A:DPP stat (id  416 val 0x0000000004A07F7E) P:00000002 I2: -ba-classification
F  24 U:  0 Pi: 1 G:22 E:    508 H:0 A:DPP stat (id  430 val 0x000000000004F5A7) P:00000002 I2: -ba-classification

Comment: @martineau How can i make sure that every thing inside the string is properly escaped and treated as one large string instead of couple of randomly delimited string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use the [shlex.quote()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote) function to get the `self.description` argument quoted properly for passing it as an argument.

Note you might be better off piping the data into the other process since there is so much of it.